# Как заменить в участках двойной слэш на одинарный на странице?

Tags: javascript

На странице есть ссылки вида
https://site.ru//search
Необходимо заменить на всей странице двойной слэш на одинарный перед search
Подскажите как это сделать скриптом именно здесь произвести замену site.ru**//**search? 
Ссылки формируются автоматически, вручную править нет возможности.
Спасибо

Comment: Почему бы не исправить тот код, который занимается автоматическим формированием ссылок?

Comment: @andreymal Потому что тот скрипт, который формирует эти ссылки находится на другом сервере (на чужом), а если скопировать этот файл скрипта и прописать у себя формирование ссылок прекращается

Answer (score -1):

```html
<p id="lol"></p>


<script type="text/javascript">
 


var changeAvariable = 'http://lol//lol';


var xy = document.querySelector('#lol');


result= changeAvariable.replace(/\/\//g, "/");
xy.innerHTML = result;


</script>
```

Аркадий, вам нужно править регулярные выражения и убрать http:// чтоб пропускало ,как вы догадались я не знаю как прописать регулярные выражения, так что дописывайте сами

Comment: Ivanova мне нужно на всей странице вот это  site.ru//search заменить на это site.ru/search

Comment: Ну и в чем проблема ? напишите (допишите) regexp и применить ко всей странице. Ну или тем более если нету http:// то уже готовое решение я вам подкинул

Comment: Ivanova Конечно же есть https, иначе бы это не было кликабельной ссылкой, как дописать я тоже не умею)